# ACPL217 minimum forward voltage

Tags: transistors, opto-isolator

my question is about the ACPL-217 Optocoupler, i use it to control P MOSFET transistor.
The ACPL-217 work with the following schema:
[image: ACPL-217]

I want to leave the pin 1 anode of the diode not connected in my schema.
[image]

Is there  any risk to enable the P MOSFET if i leave the PIN 1 not connected ?

Comment: From the datasheet of the Optocoupler http://www.avagotech.com/docs/AV02-0470EN figure 6 the minimum forward voltage and current are 1V for 1mA in 25°C, so i think if the pin 1 is NC there is no risk to enable the P-MOSFET, am i right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any risk to enable the P MOSFET if i leave the PIN 1 not
>   connected ?

With pin 1 not connected there is no current into the photodiode and hence, according to the diagram you posted: -

[image]

V\$_{CE}\$ will be high (due to R\$_L\$) and deactivate the P channel MOSFET (assumes gate connected to V\$_{CE}\$ and source connected to V\$_{CC}\$).

Comment: yes andy, your assumption is right for the P channel MOSFET

Answer (score 0):

The [ACPL-217](http://www.avagotech.com/docs/AV02-0470EN) opto shows on page 4, `dark collector current = 100nA @ 48V across the collector-emitter.` So when the LED anode is disconnected (pin 1), there is no light created, and the current that can flow through the transistor is 100nA. If the PMOS has a suitable pulling input resistor to ensure it's gate voltage is correct with this 100nA load, then it will work.